# How does discontinuous distribution provide evidence for evolution?

Tags: evolution

One of the evidences for evolution is bio-geographical evidence.

In it,'discontinuous distribution' is mostly cited as an evidence.

For example,

Alligators are found only in south-eastern US & eastern  China; elephants are found only in Africa & in & around India; lung fishes are found only in South America, Australia, Africa.

Their distribution is discontinuous due to possible changes like continental drift etcetera.

But, I am not understanding how these discontinuous distributions prove evolution.

Can anyone help me explain how they provide evidence for evolution?

Comment: Could you link to a source using the discontinuous distribution as evidence for evolution?

Comment: @rg255: After googling it, I got this: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=E_ooNitL-pkC&pg=SA1-PA88&lpg=SA1-PA88&dq=discontinuous+distribution+proof+of+evolution&source=bl&ots=jkto-JYwcb&sig=Xh2RcSy3tVxRecdtNKxC0t6IYvw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3-aO7xYTLAhVGH44KHQdOCMEQ6AEISjAI#v=onepage&q=discontinuous%20distribution%20proof%20of%20evolution&f=false

Comment: It doesn't let me view that - do you have another source? ("you have either reached a page that is unavailable or you have reached your viewing limit for this book")

Comment: @rg255: Well, you can google out that; you can find many links. Would it work if I take snapshot of my book and upload it here?

Comment: I would like to see how people are using it as evidence, so context would be good (perhaps quote the text) - then I can try to explain why they consider it evidence

Comment: @rg255: Actually it would be too long if I quote; I'll upload a snapshot.